# Update Database using Laravel Schedule Cronjob

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run an Eloquent model to insert data to the database, I tried to run a test run using Laravel schedule and cronjobs, below is my code

This is my `App\Console\kernel.php`

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\test',
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    $schedule->command('check:test')->everyMinute();

}
```

And my `App\Console\Commands\test`

```
protected $signature = 'check:test';
public function handle()
{

        try {
            $test = new Test([
                "user_id" => 1,
                "data_one"=>321,
            ]);
            $test->save();
            return response()->json('successfully added');

        } catch (exception $e) {
            return response()->json('error', $e);

        }

}
```

and my `crontab -e` code is,

```
* * * * * php /opt/lampp/htdocs/testProj/artisan schedule:run 1>> 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/testProj/schedule.log 2>&1
```

when excecuted the log I get is,

> Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.2' 'artisan' check:test > '/dev/null' 2>&1

And there is no change in the database either.
What am i doing wrong, Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to used like that in `crontab -e`

```
* * * * *  php /opt/lampp/htdocs/testProj/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

`kernel.php` file store log in log file using laravel

```
protected $commands = [
     Commands\test::class,
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    $schedule->command(Commands\test::class)->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/scheduler.log'));

}
```

and test command should like this

```
protected $signature = 'check:test';
public function handle()
{
    try {
        $test = new Test()
        $test->user_id = 1;
        $test->data_one= 321;
        $test->save();
        return $this->info('successfully added');

    } catch (exception $e) {
       return $this->warning('successfully added');
    }
}
```

Comment: i get this log >sudo: unknown user: php
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: i updated the answer (remove sudo -u) @NaveedSheriffdeen

Comment: @Naveed again update answer if getting error then read this article https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-task-scheduling-with-cron-job-example

Comment: the above error was solved but i got an error PDOException::("could not find driver") I got this error when i was trying to use laravel Jobs too

Comment: which version u running in ubunutu?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 php 7.2 laravel 5.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182023/discussion-between-jignesh-joisar-and-naveed-sheriffdeen).