# My laravel's task scheduling not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks

Trying to do task scheduling but not working properly. I set the time and wrote the commands but not running.

Here is my commands;

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\allestates;

protected $signature = 'bot:mitsui';
```

Also my Kernel is here:

```
protected $commands = [
        //
        Commands\mitsui::class,
    ];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('bot:mitsui')->everyFiveMinutes();
    }
```

What am I missing here? Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: did you get any error

Comment: may be duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851294/laravel-update-database-using-laravel-schedule-cronjob/52852962#52852962

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta I don't get any error. actually I get nothing.

Comment: This is just minor problem, Edit your question and add your full mitsui command code and your kernel code as well. showing some portion only is hard to understand for people who try to help you. Also what type of hosting are you using?

Comment: run `php artistan bot:mitsui` in you proect terminal diractory

Comment: yes, that is manual way but I am trying to do it automaticly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the schedule cron.? You need to add this into your cpanel crons or cronjob.

```
php {project_path}/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If not add the above command to your cron jobs and run it everyminute.

Here the steps if you have root access,

```
crontab -e
//Add follow line to crontab
* * * * *  php {project_path}/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: actually mate, u I don't understand what is schedule cron? Do I need to do something else after the or before laravel's task schedule?

Comment: Follow this. [Cron Job tut.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpanel/cpanel_cron_jobs.htm)

 or check this for more about [Laravel Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling)

Comment: I'm trying the install cpanel, but can't install because of the vps?

Comment: If you don't have cpanel use ssh and use crontab method.

Comment: thanks for guiding me mate, but which directory do I need to enter crontab -e? home or...?

Comment: You can do anywhere, it will open the editor and add the line I specified.

Comment: thanks mate, it's running now. But, one last question now I can control the time with kernel right? Or do I need to go crontab and change the * * * * ?

Comment: you can control  time with kernel